# Returning null from model function

Tags: codeigniter, model

#### I want to select the records from database but this function returns null.

*model*

```
function pub_article()
{
    $where=array('public'=>'1');
    $query=$this->db->get_where('article',$where);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query->result();
    else
        return false;
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You're code looks fine.  Have you checked to see if your query is correct?

Comment: add `echo $this->db->last_query()` after `get_where` call. You can see  last query executed.

Comment: @Pattle yes the query is correct.

Comment: @kumar_v I can not see the result of $this->db->last_query() in my view.